# Use coqtop to check type of expression

Tags: coq

I'm curious about the type of the Coq entities equivalent to connectives in logic. For the sake of specificity, let's say `->` and `/\`. If `->` is a magical non-[first-class entity], then let's just use `/\` as the entity. I'm curious whether its domain is Prop or Set.

Is it possible to use `coqtop` to get the type of an expression?

I want to do something similar to the following with ghci.

```
> ghci
:GHCi, version 8.6.3:  :? for help
Prelude> :t (**)
(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/\` and `->` are both notations, rather than actual constants in Coq. To find their signatures, you have to first determine what they are a notation for. Running the command `Locate "/\".` should output something along the lines of

```
Notation
"A /\ B" := and A B : type_scope
(default interpretation)
```

So `/\` is a notation for the constant `and`. Then you can use the command `Check` to find its type. `Check and.` gives

```
and
     : Prop -> Prop -> Prop
```

So `and` takes two `Prop`s and gives a `Prop`.

Similarly, `A -> B` is a notation for `forall _: A, B`. Unlike `and`, `forall` isn't a constant, but rather a keyword in the language of Coq, so you can't use `Check forall.` to get the signature. In this case, you could look in [the reference manual for products](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/gallina-specification-language.html#products) and see that

> The expression `forall ident : type, term` denotes the product of the
>   variable `ident` of type `type`, over the term `term`. As for abstractions,
>   `forall` is followed by a binder list, and products over several
>   variables are equivalent to an iteration of one-variable products.
>   Note that `term` is intended to be a type.

So that means that both `A` and `B` should be types, which means they could be elements of any of the universes `Prop`, `Set` or `Type`.

Comment: You actually don't have to locate the notation first, you can directly check with `About "/\"`. However, this only works if the notation is a reference to a single identifier; Locate is more generally useful for all notations.